# How can I find a matching between two independent sets of features extracted from two images of the same scene captured by two different cameras?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, projective-geometry

I need to find matching between two independent sets of features extracted from two images of the same scene captured by two different cameras.
I'm using the HumanEvaI data set, so I have the calibration matrices of the cameras (in this particular case BW1 and BW2).

I can not use method like simple correlation, SIFT or SURF to solve the problem because the cameras are quite far away from each other and also rotated. So the differences between the images are big and there is occlusion as well.

I have been focused in finding an Homography between the captured images based on ground truth points matching that I have been able to build due to the calibration information I already have.
Once I have this homography I will use a perfect matching (Hungarian algorithm) to find the best correspondence. The importance of the homography here is that is the way I have to calculate the distance between the points.

So far everything seems fine, my problem is that I haven't been able to find a good homography . I have tried RANSAC method, gold standard method with sampson distance (this is a nonlinear optimization approach) and mainly everything from a book called 'Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision' Second Edition by Richard Hartley.

I have implemented everything in matlab so far.

Is there another way to do this? I'm I in the right path? If so what could I have been doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method I think you might find useful is described [here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Abstracts/ijcv10_pearl-abs.html).
This approach tries to fit local models to group of points. Its global optimization method allows it to outperform RANSAC when several distinct local models exists.
I also believe they have code available.

Answer (score 2):

You can try these two methods:

1. A new point matching algorithm for non-rigid registration (uses Thin-plate Spline) - relatively slower.
2. Point Set Registration: Coherent Point Drift (faster and more accurate I feel).

As far as 2nd method is concerned, I feel that it gives very good registration result in presence of outliers, it is fast and is able to recover complex transformations. But the 1st method is also a well-known method in registration field and you may try that as well.

Try understanding the core of the algorithm and then move on to the codes available online.

1. Thin plate spline [here](http://noodle.med.yale.edu/~chui/tps-rpm.html) - Download the TPS-RPM demo.
2. Point Set Registration: Coherent Point Drift [here](https://sites.google.com/site/myronenko/research/cpd)

Answer (score 2):

You might find my solution interesting. It is a pure numpy [implementation](https://github.com/siavashk/Python-CPD) of the Coherent Point Drift algorithm.

Here is an example:

```
from functools import partial
from scipy.io import loadmat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

class RigidRegistration(object):
    def __init__(self, X, Y, R=None, t=None, s=None, sigma2=None, maxIterations=100, tolerance=0.001, w=0):
    if X.shape[1] != Y.shape[1]:
        raise 'Both point clouds must have the same number of dimensions!'

    self.X             = X
    self.Y             = Y
    (self.N, self.D)   = self.X.shape
    (self.M, _)        = self.Y.shape
    self.R             = np.eye(self.D) if R is None else R
    self.t             = np.atleast_2d(np.zeros((1, self.D))) if t is None else t
    self.s             = 1 if s is None else s
    self.sigma2        = sigma2
    self.iteration     = 0
    self.maxIterations = maxIterations
    self.tolerance     = tolerance
    self.w             = w
    self.q             = 0
    self.err           = 0

def register(self, callback):
    self.initialize()

    while self.iteration < self.maxIterations and self.err > self.tolerance:
        self.iterate()
        callback(X=self.X, Y=self.Y)

    return self.Y, self.s, self.R, self.t

def iterate(self):
    self.EStep()
    self.MStep()
    self.iteration = self.iteration + 1

def MStep(self):
    self.updateTransform()
    self.transformPointCloud()
    self.updateVariance()

def updateTransform(self):
    muX = np.divide(np.sum(np.dot(self.P, self.X), axis=0), self.Np)
    muY = np.divide(np.sum(np.dot(np.transpose(self.P), self.Y), axis=0), self.Np)

    self.XX = self.X - np.tile(muX, (self.N, 1))
    YY      = self.Y - np.tile(muY, (self.M, 1))

    self.A = np.dot(np.transpose(self.XX), np.transpose(self.P))
    self.A = np.dot(self.A, YY)

    U, _, V = np.linalg.svd(self.A, full_matrices=True)
    C = np.ones((self.D, ))
    C[self.D-1] = np.linalg.det(np.dot(U, V))

    self.R = np.dot(np.dot(U, np.diag(C)), V)

    self.YPY = np.dot(np.transpose(self.P1), np.sum(np.multiply(YY, YY), axis=1))

    self.s = np.trace(np.dot(np.transpose(self.A), self.R)) / self.YPY

    self.t = np.transpose(muX) - self.s * np.dot(self.R, np.transpose(muY))

def transformPointCloud(self, Y=None):
    if not Y:
        self.Y = self.s * np.dot(self.Y, np.transpose(self.R)) + np.tile(np.transpose(self.t), (self.M, 1))
        return
    else:
        return self.s * np.dot(Y, np.transpose(self.R)) + np.tile(np.transpose(self.t), (self.M, 1))

def updateVariance(self):
    qprev = self.q

    trAR     = np.trace(np.dot(self.A, np.transpose(self.R)))
    xPx      = np.dot(np.transpose(self.Pt1), np.sum(np.multiply(self.XX, self.XX), axis =1))
    self.q   = (xPx - 2 * self.s * trAR + self.s * self.s * self.YPY) / (2 * self.sigma2) + self.D * self.Np/2 * np.log(self.sigma2)
    self.err = np.abs(self.q - qprev)

    self.sigma2 = (xPx - self.s * trAR) / (self.Np * self.D)

    if self.sigma2 <= 0:
        self.sigma2 = self.tolerance / 10

def initialize(self):
    self.Y = self.s * np.dot(self.Y, np.transpose(self.R)) + np.repeat(self.t, self.M, axis=0)
    if not self.sigma2:
        XX = np.reshape(self.X, (1, self.N, self.D))
        YY = np.reshape(self.Y, (self.M, 1, self.D))
        XX = np.tile(XX, (self.M, 1, 1))
        YY = np.tile(YY, (1, self.N, 1))
        diff = XX - YY
        err  = np.multiply(diff, diff)
        self.sigma2 = np.sum(err) / (self.D * self.M * self.N)

    self.err  = self.tolerance + 1
    self.q    = -self.err - self.N * self.D/2 * np.log(self.sigma2)

def EStep(self):
    P = np.zeros((self.M, self.N))

    for i in range(0, self.M):
        diff     = self.X - np.tile(self.Y[i, :], (self.N, 1))
        diff    = np.multiply(diff, diff)
        P[i, :] = P[i, :] + np.sum(diff, axis=1)

    c = (2 * np.pi * self.sigma2) ** (self.D / 2)
    c = c * self.w / (1 - self.w)
    c = c * self.M / self.N

    P = np.exp(-P / (2 * self.sigma2))
    den = np.sum(P, axis=0)
    den = np.tile(den, (self.M, 1))
    den[den==0] = np.finfo(float).eps

    self.P   = np.divide(P, den)
    self.Pt1 = np.sum(self.P, axis=0)
    self.P1  = np.sum(self.P, axis=1)
    self.Np = np.sum(self.P1)

def visualize(X, Y, ax):
    plt.cla()
    ax.scatter(X[:,0] ,  X[:,1], color='red')
    ax.scatter(Y[:,0] ,  Y[:,1], color='blue')
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.001)

def main():
    fish = loadmat('./data/fish.mat')
    X = fish['X'] # number-of-points x number-of-dimensions array of fixed points
    Y = fish['Y'] # number-of-points x number-of-dimensions array of moving points

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    callback = partial(visualize, ax=fig.axes[0])

    reg = RigidRegistration(X, Y)
    reg.register(callback)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```